# DeclareTCBListing and write percent a file

Tags: tcolorbox, verbatim, write-file

I don't understand why the environment `mytcblisting` fails when writing the percentage symbol, I tried with `verbatim ignore percent` but it didn't work, I get the error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.23 T
      his is my 5\percent\ text
?
```

I'm using TeXLive 2020 and this is my sample file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable,skins,xparse}
\DeclareTCBListing{mytcblisting}{ O{} }
  {%
    bottom=-1mm, boxrule=0.4pt, boxsep=0mm, top=-1mm, arc=0mm,%
    title~style={draw=none,fill=none}, enhanced, autoparskip, freelance,#1%
  }
\begin{document}
% OK, from doc pag 130
\def\percent{\%}
\begin{tcblisting}{title=Normal}
%\begin{center}\bfseries
This is my 5\percent\ text
and this is my 10\% text.
%\end{center}
\end{tcblisting}

% Error

\begin{mytcblisting}
%\begin{center}\bfseries
This is my 5\percent\ text
and this is my 10\% text.
%\end{center}
\end{mytcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your own listing already fails without any sorts of percent signs. And if you replace `title~style` by `title style`, i.e. without `~`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own listing already fails without any sorts of percent signs. And if you replace `title~style` by `title style`, i.e. without `~`, it works fine.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable,skins,xparse}
\DeclareTCBListing{mytcblisting}{ O{} }
  {%
     bottom=-1mm, boxrule=0.4pt, boxsep=0mm, top=-1mm, arc=0mm,%
     title style={draw=none,fill=none},
      enhanced, autoparskip, 
    freelance,#1%
  }
\begin{document}
% OK, from doc pag 130
\def\percent{\%}
\begin{tcblisting}{title=Normal}
%\begin{center}\bfseries
This is my 5\percent\ text
and this is my 10\% text.
%\end{center}
\end{tcblisting}

% No rror

\begin{mytcblisting}
%\begin{center}\bfseries
This is my 5\percent\ text
and this is my 10\% text.
%\end{center}
\end{mytcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, I assume that this is not the final design of your box. And I think I know why one might think one has to add a `~`. Well, this is a long and unfortunate discussion, no need to fuel it further, especially during these crazy days.

Comment: It's just an outline :) ...the style comes later, but I want the code to work first :(

Comment: But, if it solves the question :)